# Cocos2d-x editor for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, editor, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm currently using Ubuntu for developing purposes and in free time I wanted to check out Cocos2d-x. The problem is that there aren't provided any officially supported editors for Linux. Regarding the fact that Cocos2d-x has very poor documentation, I don't think I can use it without a decent editor. My question is, is there such an editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sensible code editor for Cocos2dx and Linux is Eclipse.
Here you have some configuration tutorials:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Build_an_Android_Project_with_Eclipse
http://borjarefoyo.com/2013/07/02/setup-cocos2dx-environment-in-linux-for-android/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Unfortunately there is no UI Editor for Cocos2dx on Linux :(

Comment: Clion is a pretty good IDE for cocos2d-x on Linux